# submit button not working due to js file in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I **created autocomplete listbox** from js.I download this js.

but **due to this js implementation in my code**...

**my save and search button not working.**...

but **when I comment this js file...submit button works properly..**

but this js is also necessary for me to make listbox as autocomplete textbox...

plz suggest me what to change in this js..to make both button and listbox works.

my save button code

```
<?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']))
{}
?>
```

below is my listbox

```
<select class="special-flexselect"  id="society" name="society" tabindex="5" >                      
     <option  value="" ></option>
      <?php foreach ($society as $soc){ ?>  
 <option  value="<?php echo $soc["society"]; ?>"><?php echo $soc["society"]; ?></option>
  <?php }?>
                            </select>
```

below is my js code

```
/**
 * flexselect: a jQuery plugin, version: 0.6.0 (2014-08-05)
 * @requires jQuery v1.3 or later
 *
 * FlexSelect is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to convert a select box into
 * a Quicksilver-style, autocompleting, flex matching selection tool.
 *
 * For usage and examples, visit:
 * http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2012, Ryan McGeary (ryan -[at]- mcgeary [*dot*] org)
 */
(function($) {
  $.flexselect = function(select, options) { this.init(select, options); };

  $.extend($.flexselect.prototype, {
    settings: {
      allowMismatch: false,
      allowMismatchBlank: true, // If "true" a user can backspace such that the value is nothing (even if no blank value was provided in the original criteria)
      sortBy: 'score', // 'score' || 'name'
      preSelection: true,
      hideDropdownOnEmptyInput: false,
      selectedClass: "flexselect_selected",
      dropdownClass: "flexselect_dropdown",
      showDisabledOptions: false,
      inputIdTransform:    function(id)   { return id + "_flexselect"; },
      inputNameTransform:  function(name) { return; },
      dropdownIdTransform: function(id)   { return id + "_flexselect_dropdown"; }
    },
    select: null,
    input: null,
    dropdown: null,
    dropdownList: null,
    cache: [],
    results: [],
    lastAbbreviation: null,
    abbreviationBeforeFocus: null,
    selectedIndex: 0,
    picked: false,
    allowMouseMove: true,
    dropdownMouseover: false, // Workaround for poor IE behaviors
    indexOptgroupLabels: false,

    init: function(select, options) {
      this.settings = $.extend({}, this.settings, options);
      this.select = $(select);
      this.preloadCache();
      this.renderControls();
      this.wire();
    },

    preloadCache: function() {
      var name, group, text, disabled;
      var indexGroup = this.settings.indexOptgroupLabels;
      this.cache = this.select.find("option").map(function() {
        name = $(this).text();
        group = $(this).parent("optgroup").attr("label");
        text = indexGroup ? [name, group].join(" ") : name;
        disabled = $(this).parent("optgroup").attr("disabled") || $(this).attr('disabled');
        return { text: $.trim(text), name: $.trim(name), value: $(this).val(), disabled: disabled, score: 0.0 };
      });
    },

    renderControls: function() {
      var selected = this.settings.preSelection ? this.select.find("option:selected") : null;

      this.input = $("<input type='text' autocomplete='off' />").attr({
        id: this.settings.inputIdTransform(this.select.attr("id")),
        name: this.settings.inputNameTransform(this.select.attr("name")),
        accesskey: this.select.attr("accesskey"),
        tabindex: this.select.attr("tabindex"),
        style: this.select.attr("style"),
        placeholder: this.select.attr("data-placeholder")
      }).addClass(this.select.attr("class")).val($.trim(selected ? selected.text():  '')).css({
        visibility: 'visible'
      });

      this.dropdown = $("<div></div>").attr({
        id: this.settings.dropdownIdTransform(this.select.attr("id"))
      }).addClass(this.settings.dropdownClass);
      this.dropdownList = $("<ul></ul>");
      this.dropdown.append(this.dropdownList);

      this.select.after(this.input).hide();
      $("body").append(this.dropdown);
    },

    wire: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.input.click(function() {
        self.lastAbbreviation = null;
        self.focus();
      });

      this.input.mouseup(function(event) {
        // This is so Safari selection actually occurs.
        event.preventDefault();
      });

      this.input.focus(function() {
        self.abbreviationBeforeFocus = self.input.val();
        self.input.select();
        if (!self.picked) self.filterResults();
      });

      this.input.blur(function() {
        if (!self.dropdownMouseover) {
          self.hide();
          if (self.settings.allowMismatchBlank && $.trim($(this).val()) == '')
            self.setValue('');
          if (!self.settings.allowMismatch && !self.picked)
            self.reset();
        }
        if (self.settings.hideDropdownOnEmptyInput)
          self.dropdownList.show();
      });

      this.dropdownList.mouseover(function(event) {
        if (!self.allowMouseMove) {
          self.allowMouseMove = true;
          return;
        }

        if (event.target.tagName == "LI") {
          var rows = self.dropdown.find("li");
          self.markSelected(rows.index($(event.target)));
        }
      });
      this.dropdownList.mouseleave(function() {
        self.markSelected(-1);
      });
      this.dropdownList.mouseup(function(event) {
        self.pickSelected();
        self.focusAndHide();
      });
      this.dropdown.mouseover(function(event) {
        self.dropdownMouseover = true;
      });
      this.dropdown.mouseleave(function(event) {
        self.dropdownMouseover = false;
      });
      this.dropdown.mousedown(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });

      this.input.keyup(function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 13: // return
            event.preventDefault();
            self.pickSelected();
            self.focusAndHide();
            break;
          case 27: // esc
            event.preventDefault();
            self.reset();
            self.focusAndHide();
            break;
          default:
            self.filterResults();
            break;
        }
        if (self.settings.hideDropdownOnEmptyInput){
          if(self.input.val() == "")
            self.dropdownList.hide();
          else
            self.dropdownList.show();
        }
      });

      this.input.keydown(function(event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 9:  // tab
            self.pickSelected();
            self.hide();
            break;
          case 33: // pgup
            event.preventDefault();
            self.markFirst();
            break;
          case 34: // pgedown
            event.preventDefault();
            self.markLast();
            break;
          case 38: // up
            event.preventDefault();
            self.moveSelected(-1);
            break;
          case 40: // down
            event.preventDefault();
            self.moveSelected(1);
            break;
          case 13: // return
          case 27: // esc
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            break;
        }
      });

      var input = this.input;
      this.select.change(function () {
        input.val($.trim($(this).find('option:selected').text()));
      });
    },

    filterResults: function() {
      var showDisabled = this.settings.showDisabledOptions;
      var abbreviation = this.input.val();
      if (abbreviation == this.lastAbbreviation) return;

      var results = [];
      $.each(this.cache, function() {
        if (this.disabled && !showDisabled) return;
        this.score = LiquidMetal.score(this.text, abbreviation);
        if (this.score > 0.0) results.push(this);
      });
      this.results = results;

      if (this.settings.sortBy == 'score')
        this.sortResultsByScore();
      else if (this.settings.sortBy == 'name')
        this.sortResultsByName();

      this.renderDropdown();
      this.markFirst();
      this.lastAbbreviation = abbreviation;
      this.picked = false;
      this.allowMouseMove = false;
    },

    sortResultsByScore: function() {
      this.results.sort(function(a, b) { return b.score - a.score; });
    },

    sortResultsByName: function() {
      this.results.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name < b.name ? -1 : (a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0); });
    },

    renderDropdown: function() {
      var showDisabled = this.settings.showDisabledOptions;
      var dropdownBorderWidth = this.dropdown.outerWidth() - this.dropdown.innerWidth();
      var inputOffset = this.input.offset();
      this.dropdown.css({
        width: (this.input.outerWidth() - dropdownBorderWidth) + "px",
        top: (inputOffset.top + this.input.outerHeight()) + "px",
        left: inputOffset.left + "px",
        maxHeight: ''
      });

      var html = '';
      var disabledAttribute = '';
      $.each(this.results, function() {
        if (this.disabled && !showDisabled) return;
        disabledAttribute = this.disabled ? ' class="disabled"' : '';
        html += '<li' + disabledAttribute + '>' + this.name + '</li>';
      });
      this.dropdownList.html(html);
      this.adjustMaxHeight();
      this.dropdown.show();
    },

    adjustMaxHeight: function() {
      var maxTop = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - this.dropdown.outerHeight();
      var top = parseInt(this.dropdown.css('top'), 10);
      this.dropdown.css('max-height', top > maxTop ? (Math.max(0, maxTop - top + this.dropdown.innerHeight()) + 'px') : '');
    },

    markSelected: function(n) {
      if (n < 0 || n >= this.results.length) return;

      var rows = this.dropdown.find("li");
      rows.removeClass(this.settings.selectedClass);

      var row = $(rows[n]);
      if (row.hasClass('disabled')) {
        this.selectedIndex = null;
        return;
      }

      this.selectedIndex = n;
      row.addClass(this.settings.selectedClass);
      var top = row.position().top;
      var delta = top + row.outerHeight() - this.dropdown.height();
      if (delta > 0) {
        this.allowMouseMove = false;
        this.dropdown.scrollTop(this.dropdown.scrollTop() + delta);
      } else if (top < 0) {
        this.allowMouseMove = false;
        this.dropdown.scrollTop(Math.max(0, this.dropdown.scrollTop() + top));
      }
    },

    pickSelected: function() {
      var selected = this.results[this.selectedIndex];
      if (selected && !selected.disabled) {
        this.input.val(selected.name);
        this.setValue(selected.value);
        this.picked = true;
      } else if (this.settings.allowMismatch) {
        this.setValue.val("");
      } else {
        this.reset();
      }
    },

    setValue: function(val) {
      if (this.select.val() === val) return;
      this.select.val(val).change();
    },

    hide: function() {
      this.dropdown.hide();
      this.lastAbbreviation = null;
    },

    moveSelected: function(n) { this.markSelected(this.selectedIndex+n); },
    markFirst:    function()  { this.markSelected(0); },
    markLast:     function()  { this.markSelected(this.results.length - 1); },
    reset:        function()  { this.input.val(this.abbreviationBeforeFocus); },
    focus:        function()  { this.input.focus(); },
    focusAndHide: function()  { this.focus(); this.hide(); }
  });

  $.fn.flexselect = function(options) {
    this.each(function() {
      if (this.tagName == "SELECT") new $.flexselect(this, options);
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you check if there are any console errors..??

Comment: yes my form has already works perfect before js implementation..

Comment: yes there is no console error also..

Comment: yes this shows my variable name in javascript popups...

Answer (score 0):

find this in your js page and Remove this from js file,bcoz this shoud stop user to submit form data

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
          alert($(this).serialize());
          return false;
        });
```